# PHP Replace Emoticon from MySQL Can't looping

Tags: php, mysql

I have some problem with my syntax coding about emoticon.
it can replaced as well in first post, but in next post it can't replaced.
it not looping as well.

you can see the images in:

http://postimg.org/image/srph22j8d/

```
# POPULATED EMOTICON
    $sqlEMO = "SELECT * FROM apprtcfg WHERE obj_typ = 'EMO' ORDER BY id ASC;";
    $queryEMO = mysql_query($sqlEMO);

    while ($rsltEmo=mysql_fetch_array($queryEMO)) {

        $emo_code = $rsltEmo['obj_link'];
        $emo_img = $rsltEmo['obj_source'];
    }

    echo $content = str_replace($emo_code,'<img src="image/'.$emo_img.'">', $row['content']);
```

Comment: `echo $content = str_replace($emo_code,'<img src="image/'.$emo_img.'">', $row['content']);` should be inside while loop, I think

Comment: i already try, but it can double loop for $row['content']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your emotions with images, inside while and echo it after end of while.

```
$sqlEMO = "SELECT * FROM apprtcfg WHERE obj_typ = 'EMO' ORDER BY id ASC;";
$queryEMO = mysql_query($sqlEMO);

$content = $row['content'];
while ($rsltEmo=mysql_fetch_array($queryEMO)) {

        $emo_code = $rsltEmo['obj_link'];
        $emo_img = $rsltEmo['obj_source'];
        $content = str_replace($emo_code,'<img src="image/'.$emo_img.'">', $content);
}

echo $content;
```

Comment: then cross check `$emo_code` should contain the emotion which needs to  be replaced with respective image, in content,

Comment: No, actually try my updated answer .. Note, I have assigned the value of `$row['content']` to `$content` above while, and used `$content` inside while .. so all occurrence get replaced.

Comment: yes of course, you can see this picture when im try to print the $emo_code and $emo_img http://postimg.org/image/ta8vppcer/